# Client or server check if insert or update in RESTful architecture

Tags: php, rest, mysql

Before I began developing a RESTful API I used a query similar to this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO availability (user_id, date, status) " .
         "VALUES ('".$id."', '".$date."', '".$status."') " .
         "ON DUPLICATE KEY " .
         "UPDATE status='".$status."'";
```

Yes, I know it's subject to SQL injection. Anyway, I'm having trouble deciding if this should be a POST or PUT request since it can insert or update. I got to thinking: maybe it's better to have both POST and PUT methods in the API and then the client determines which one to call.

Is this usually how RESTful APIs handle this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I got to thinking: maybe it's better to have both POST and PUT methods in the API and then the client determines which one to call.
>
> Is this usually how RESTful APIs handle this scenario?

Not really.  Think about how you would implement this in a web site.  Somebody would go to the home page, and then follow a link to a form allowing them to provide the data they would want to use, and then they would submit the form, and get a message back announcing whether the submission was successful.

The representation of the form would describe the identifier for the resource to submit the request to, and the method to use (in an HTML form, that would always be a POST, of course).

So you could use POST, or PUT, or alternate back and forth, or do whatever you like by simply altering the representation of the form.

From a REST perspective, the only important thing is that you respect the uniform interface; which in this case means that the semantics of your messages are aligned with the HTTP specification.

REST really doesn't care which method you use, so long as (a) you use it correctly according to the uniform interface, and (b) the client discovers which method to use by consuming the hypermedia provided by the server.

Semantically, a [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) is supposed to be a complete replacement.  RFC 7231 is the relevant standard.

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload

It's a little bit weird that you insert `$date` but you don't update it.  Not wrong -- but tough to tell from the example whether `date` is part of the "representation enclosed in the request message payload."  The semantics of PUT allow clients and intermediaries to make certain assumptions about the state of the updated resource without sending a GET to the server -- it's the responsibility of the server to ensure that those assumptions hold.

Answer (score 5):

It might help to first look at the difference between POST and PUT.

The main difference is that PUT is intended for idempotent operations.  That is, operations that can be performed multiple times but will behave as if they were performed once. POST has no such assumption.  The significance of idempotence is that the client or infrastructure can repeat the request if it doesn't seem to have been acknowledged. With a POST request, this may cause unintended consequences.  This is why your browser warns you if you refresh a page that was produced via a POST request.

The operation in your question is idempotent, so PUT can and should be used. A POST request would be appropriate for operations that are not idempotent like operations that are more like RPC calls or, more in the spirit of REST and HTTP, creating new records. For example, if you had an auto-increment ID field and each INSERT created a new record, you'd use POST because such an operation is not idempotent: executing it twice will create two new records.